Normal vector field of a hypersurface in $S^{n+1}$
Question
Denote $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}=\mathbb{R}^{r+1}\times \mathbb{R}^{s+1}$, where $s+r=n$. We write a vector $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ as $\xi=\xi_1+\xi_2$.
Let $f:M\rightarrow S^{n+1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ be an isometrically immersed hypersurface of $S^{n+1}$. Write the position vector field of $M$ as:
$$ X=a_1\xi_1+a_2\xi_2 \quad a_1^2+a_2^2=1, \  ||\xi_1||=||\xi_2||=1 $$
Show that
(1) The unit normal vector field of $M$ can be expressed as:
$$ e_{n+1}=-a_2\xi_1+a_1\xi_2$$
I don't know how to show $e_{n+1}$ is orthogonal to $TM$, it seems that we know nothing about $Y\in \mathscr{X}(M)$. Or maybe $s,r$ are not given numbers, and we need to choose $s,r$ carefully?
Any hints, comments or solutions are welcomed. THANKS!
Edit: I think the question above is not rigorous. By the way, the full question is talking about Clifford minimal surface. I wonder in that case what conditions should be imposed on $M$ so that we can prove (1)?

What do you mean you know nothing about $X$? It’s the position vector, so it’s the unit normal to the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^{n+2}$. Is $e_{n+1}$ tangent to the sphere? To decide if it’s orthogonal to $M$ we presumably need to know more about $M$. I suspect you’ve omitted some information. (Oh, and by $t$ you meant $r$.)

@TedShifrin Hi professor, sorry for the typo, I mean I know nothing about the vector fields on $M$ :)
I agree with you, so I suspect the question (1) hopes us to show that we can always select $s,r$ such that $e_{n+1}$ can be expressed in this way? (Seems boring, since when $s,r$ varies, it forms a frame of $TS^{n+1}$?)

There has to be more information. You can easily give examples and counterexamples even when $n=1$.

@TedShifrin Yeah, I agree.

As the question is phrased, $e_{n+1}$ is normal to a connected $M$ if and only if $a_2=ca_1$ for some constant $c$. This in turn tells us that $a_1$ and $a_2$ must be constant. In the Clifford torus case, that should be true, right?

@TedShifrin Thank you! In this case can we simply show this by noticing that $\left\langle \mathrm{d}X, e_{n+1}\right\rangle =0 $ ? (To be honest I am a bit confused with this notation)

Write $df$ if you like.
